# How To Stop keyBoard Appearence at click event on UITextview?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, keyboard, uitextview

In my IPad Application i am using TextView only for Text Displaying.As i need to display a Larger Text Thats Why i am  using UITextview due to its Scrolling Property instead of using UILabel. 
In my application i do not need to edit Text in UITextview ,but problem for me is that when i click on Textview for scrolling the keyboard appear its hide my textview so i want that my keyboard is never appear on click event.i make a search but not find any Suitable solution.Any help will be appriated.Thanx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER** (previous one was not working properly)

OK so since that is not working because it disables scrolling also, you should try to:

Implement UITextFieldDelegate protocol
In your view controller add the text

```
@interface YourViewController () <UITextViewDelegate>
```

In viewDidLoad set yourself as a delegate:

```
yourUITextView.delegate = self;
```

Implement the delegate method below:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{ 
   return NO; 
}
```

When the textview is about to edit the text, this method will be called automatically. It returns no, so the editing won't start.

It is very important that you undo the changes from the previous answers: **Do not set the editable field to NO**

I tried it and it's working. Hope it helps!

**OLD ANSWER**

when you declare the variable, or in your viewdidload method, set the editable property to NO:

```
yourUITextView.editable = NO;
```

or

```
[yourUITextView setEditable:NO]
```

That should prevent the keyboard from appearing.

Comment: using this its not allow me for Scrolling

Comment: @Albert. I edited my answer with another method. It should dismiss the keyboard but still allow scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Go to .XIB file and you can uncheck behavior editable or programmatically

`textView.editable = NO;`

Comment: using this its not allow me  for Scrolling.