# Disabling Keyboard sound programmatically

Tags: ios, keyboard

is it possible to disable the keynoard sound programmatically when user types on uitextfield?

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562975/how-to-stop-keyboard-appearence-at-click-event-on-uitextview

Comment: @HarshBhikadia totally unrelated link IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that it is not possible. The clicking sound is a global setting which can be enabled/disabled in the iOS-Settings. Changing or temporarily disabling it from an app would therefore make not any sense.